# Does CnosDB support batch query?

Tags: cnosdb

I checked CnosDB's [RESTFUL API](https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/reference/rest_api.html). I only found the interface `/api/v1/sql` to query data.

But I didn't find a manual for bulk queries.

Does CnosDB support one HTTP request to contain multiple SQLs and return the data of these SQLs together?

Request body like this:

```
select 1;
select 2;
```

Return body like this:

```json
{
    [ 
        [{"Int64": 1}], // first sql result
        [{"Int64": 2}], // second sql result
    ]
}
```